# Trying to use FxCop with repeatedly upgraded MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fxcop

I am trying to use FxCop on a project that has been upgraded from MVC 1 through MVC 3.  The first time I ran my project, it asked me to locate MVC 3 for it.  Once I did, it continued on for a bit and then asked me to find MVC 1, which I find odd because I no longer have it installed on this machine and the website operates just fine.  This is the message it is giving me:

[image: FxCop wants System.Web.Mvc 1]

In our Web.config file we have the following, which is created automatically when you upgrade versions of MVC:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of this error so FxCop will complete it's analysis of this project?

Answer (score 0):

Got same problem with FxCop. Have you checked other assemblies, that might be dependant on MVC1? AFAIK MVC1 required 3 assemblies:

```
System.Web.Mvc  
System.Web.Routing  
System.Web.Abstractions
```

Maybe Routing or Abstractions left somewhere in your references?

Comment: MVC references 3.0 and both Routing and Abstractions reference 4.0 in all projects in the solution.  System.Web.Helpers and System.Web.WebPages both reference v 1.0, however both of those references are built on the 4.0 framework, which makes me think they are not referencing MVC1.

Comment: By the way, have you changed versions in web.config in Views folder? Can't check if FxCop looks at it somehow at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround to get FxCop going you can update the FxCop configuration and set the following:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="AssemblyReferenceResolveMode" value="StrongNameIgnoringVersion" />
</appSettings>
```

Its most likely currently set to StrongName.

The allowable values are:

> **None** - Do not match strong names at all, any assembly with the same file name is considered a match.
>
> **StrongName** - Strong names including assembly name, version, culture and public key token must exactly match.
>
> **StrongNameIgnoringVersion** - Strong names including assembly name, culture and public key token must exactly match. Assemblies with an equal or greater version are considered a match.`

However I would look at your assembly with something like [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to try to determine why its still referencing the older version.